# Hyperlink in the case's comment

Tags: rest-api, api, html, hyperlink, case-comment

I am using the following Salesforce API to generate a case comment.

```
POST /services/data/v39.0/sobjects/CaseComment HTTP/1.1
Host: *******.my.salesforce.com
Content-Type: application/json
cache-control: no-cache
Postman-Token: f307fe07-8f81-4653-adca-42f6880b28cd

{
    "ParentId": "5002500000*********",
    "CommentBody": "Go here and check the best website ever: <a href=\"http://www.google.com\">Click me</a>",
    "IsPublished": "false"
}
```

I was wondering if is possible to put a hyperlink or html code in the CommentBody and make Salesforce render it. Using the GUI I am able to create an hyperlink but using the API, I was not able to.

Note: API taken from here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/api-explorer/sobject/CaseComment

The following image I have posted the first comment using the GUI the following two comments were posted using the API.
[image: Comment case post using GUI/API]

Comment: why can't you just use the API and set the comment body to `...http://www.google.com/..`? The browser or email client will render the URL as clickable

Comment: Unfortunately when I do that, the comment on the case just shows the URL as a plain text, rather than making it clickable.

Answer (score 1):

Your screenshot looks like Chatter posts, not CaseComments. To post a rich-text Chatter post, you need to use the [Chatter API's rich-text comment function](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/quickreference_post_comment_rich_text.htm).

The [`CommentBody` field on `CaseComment` is a text area](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_casecomment.htm), not rich text, so you can't insert HTML into it.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured this out myself, you're looking for the object FeedItem instead of CaseComment:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_feeditem.htm